# How to get Nofication data of other apps on Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, android-fragments, dart, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to make an app that can get the notification data of all notifications that appear on the phone. I tried using [notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/notifications#-readme-tab-) package, but using this package I can only access the name of app which sent the Notification and the timestamp, and not the actual notification itself.

I have no issue if the app asks for permission.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This feature has been added in the GitHub repo of the  [Notification](https://pub.dev/packages/notifications#-readme-tab-) package recently.It is not yet updated int the pub.dev website.

Depend on the GitHub repository of the package to use the `packageMessage` property.